# Как разрезать фото на части?

Tags: javascript, html, css, yandex-maps-api

Делаю собственную карту по шаблону от Яндекса https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/custom_map.
И там нужно целую карту разрезать на части в разных масштабах.

Посоветуйте сервис или что-то другое что сможет это сделать[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете попробовать воспользоваться [ImageMagic](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)

```
$ convert map.jpg -crop 512x512 -set filename:tile "%[fx:page.x/512]-%[fx:page.y/512]" "tiles/%[filename:tile].jpg"
```

Каждый тайл будет сохранен в отдельном файле с названием « x-y.jpg », где x — номер тайла по оси X, y — номер тайла по оси Y (порядковый отсчет начинается с левого верхнего тайла).

Answer (score 1):

Правильнее пользоваться инструкцией самого Яндекса
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/archive/doc/jsapi/1.x/dg/concepts/ymapstiler-docpage/

Там суть такова:

1. скачивайте специальную программу
2. задаёте точки привязки. Дело в том, что Ваша карта скорее всего сделана не в той проекции, что у Яндекса. И чтобы это исправить, необходимо задать соответствие точек на растовой карте реальным координаторам на местности.Чем больше точек и чем они точнее, тем лучше. Сайты с онлайн определением координат можно найти в поиске.
3. Программа сама сгенерирует нужные тайлы именно под Яндекс карты с нужными номерами тайлов и для нужных масштабов. Вручную это делать проблематично. Можно сгенерировать и полупрозрачные тайлы в формате PNG.

От себя:

1. Частенько трудно корректно привязать карту. Я лично качаю (растрирую) часть Яндекс карты, накладываю сверху свою карту в Photoshop, затем применяю марионеточную деформацию и медленно и аккуратно "натягиваю" свою карту на карту от Яндекса. А потом уже привязываю.
2. Рассмотрите вариант вообще не делать тайлы. Я лично по определённым причинам пришёл к такому решению.

   ```
    myMap = new ymaps.Map("map1", {
            center: 55.03930264,82.67716136});
    maprect= [ [55.03330264,82.67716136],
                [55.03930264,82.67716136],
                [55.03930264,82.69716136],
                [55.03330264,82.69716136]];
        RastMap = new ymaps.Polygon([maprect],
            {

            },
            {
                fillImageHref:'map.png'
            });
            myMap.geoObjects.add(RastMap);
   ```

Для наглядности тут координаты реального проекта.
Суть в том что вся не резанная, но обработанная по методу 1, карта выводится на полигон (в данном случае, прямоугольник). Координаты углов прямоугольника подбираются так, чтобы карты совпали по координатам.

Почему я делаю так? Яндекс делит всю карту на тайлы, чтобы не грузить лишние данные для не интересующей пользователя местности, особенно на больших масштабах.
В тех же проектах,где нужна своя карта, пользователь обычно так и так загружает эту карту всю. Ну разве что для каждого масштаба карту не сделаешь, придётся сразу полный размер грузить.

3. Для уменьшения размера файла карты, можно сохранить его в специальном формате PNG с ограниченной палитрой цветов. Это можно сделать в специальных редакторах типа PhotoShop. Ищите сохранение в PNG8. Сохранять в JPG не рекомендую, там нет прозрачности и по краю карты могут быть некрасивые белые поля.